# Cordova does not actually install app on android device

Tags: android, cordova, installation, apk, device

I've setup cordova 5.0.0 + android SDK API 22 ( Android 5.1.1 ) on ubuntu 12.04 to develop an app. When I run the command

`cordova run --device`

it builds without errors the APK and shows

`Total time: 3.177 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /var/www/tmp/test-app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
Using apk: /var/www/tmp/test-app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS`

which however does NOT actually installs the APK to the device.

I have tried to install the ready built APK file using

`adb install -r /var/www/tmp/test-app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk`

and it worked.

I have tried to download the APK from a web-server and install it locally on the device and it also worked, so I assume the APK itself is ok and the device is recognized.

When the APK is already installed on the device the command

`cordova run --device`

produces the same output in the console plus it starts up the app on the device but does not install the newer version it just built.

my android device is an HTC Desire 500 running Android 4.1.2, while my Android SDK is using API 22 ( Android 5.1.1 ) could that be the problem ?

Final note: I have a setup on separate machine using cordova 4.1.2 setup with Android SDK API 19 and it builds the project well and actually DO install the app.

I would appreciate your input on what might cause this strange behavior.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for sharing the method to manually install the apk, it helped me significantly, for some reason cordova's routine doesn't work for a subset of devices (It works for my Galaxy S4 but not my Galaxy W)

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be a bug in Cordova 5.0.0, I had the same problem and the answer by *proprit* in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display) solved it for me:

> On Cordova 5.0.0, adb commands to install the apk can be found at line
>   101 of file platforms\android\cordova\lib\device.js (and at line 311
>   of platforms\android\cordova\lib\emulator.js for cordova emulate
>   android):
>
> `adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"`
>
> Current command returns to me: "Error: unknown option -d"! If you
>   simply delete the "-d" option, applications run normally with cordova
>   run android.

Comment: Brilliant! Great bit of unpicking to determine where Cordova was going wrong. I'm finding that Cordova uses a lot of automation and things that can be easily fixed are made difficult to fix because error messages are not displayed, ( at least in Cordova Tools for VS2015)

Comment: Thanks! Seems the rogue `-d` was still present `emulator.js` in Cordova 5.2.0 (not sure about the latest release).

Answer (score 2):

```
cordova build

adb push "<<project_path_here>>\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk" /sdcard/

adb shell pm install -r /sdcard/android-debug.apk
```

And then you can find your app in your phone and run it ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova emulate android
```

works for the latest version as of this date.